# Menu scrolling also scrolls background screen

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, iphone, web-applications

My web application when opened on iOS mobile devices, it shows a menu icon which is present on the body. If click on menu icon, it opens menu popup modal. When we scroll on menu modal the background screen also scrolls along with the menu items. This created UI issues. I applied overflow : hidden on body when the menu is opened. That doesn't help. When i put position: fixed; then the background screen becomes white and everything on the body goes to the left. For that I also applied left: 0; right: 0; top:0; and bottom: 0; This helped in portrait view where menu background screen doesn't scroll but in landscape view it doesn't help. I am looking forward a solution which can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Here 'modal-open' is the classname which is added to the 'body' when the modal is opened. In case if its not 'modal-open', please inspect the classname and replace.

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```